# PyCharm "No tests were found"

Tags: python, unit-testing, syntax, pycharm

This is my main code

```
def return_first_name(first_name):
   return first_name
```

This is the unit test code

```
import unittest
import profile


class TestFunctionFirstName(unittest.TestCase):
   def first_name(self):
      answer = profile.return_first_name("jakub")
      self.assertEqual(answer, "jakub")
```

I really don't understand why it is not finding any unit tests. I have been sitting here for hours messing with it.[image]

Comment: Try renaming `first_name` to `test_first_name`.

Comment: It's working now. 2 hours of my life wasted. Thank you Norrius.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the docs](https://pytest.readthedocs.io/en/reorganize-docs/new-docs/user/naming_conventions.html)

> Test method names or function names should start with “test_”, as in `test_example`. Methods with names that don’t match this pattern won’t be executed as tests.

So in your case you can rename your test method to

```
def test_first_name(self):
```